# issue when using CommonsChunkPlugin with different entrypoits which only one needs it

Tags: javascript, webpack

using webpack v2, i have two entry points which should generate two bundles that can be loaded on the same page or different pages separately. I'm also using the CommonsChunkPlugin to extract all dependencies from the node_modules folder to a 3rd bundle which is only needed by the first bundle. When loading the second bundle alone on a page, it does not get initialized, because it seems to need the commonChucnks bundle to have been loaded before (hosting the webpackJsonp function) is there an option other than having two webpack configs to solve my problem?

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname),

  entry: {
    "first": "./src/js/first.js",
    "second": "./src/js/second.js",
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "target/js"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    libraryTarget: "umd"
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: "vendor",

     // automatically determine which files are from the node modules. And put them in a separate "lib" bundle
     // @see https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/#commonschunkplugin
     // this assumes your vendor imports exist in the node_modules directory
     minChunks: module => module.context && module.context.indexOf("node_modules") !== -1
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

"(two entrypoints)... that can be loaded on the same page".

This is not how it supposed to be. Entry point - is an entry point - it can be only once loaded.

What you need is:  two entrypoints chunks, with "specific" code chunks" and one common code chunk.